# Mocking HttpRequest.Form for unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

In ASP.NET, I'm trying to mock up a unit test using the HttpRequest object. The Form collection of the object is indicating the collection is readonly. Is there a way to implement this behavior for my unit tests without having to provide my own httprequest implemenation? The following snippet fails with request.Form being readonly. Tx.

```
var request = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost" + url, "");
request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] = eventTarget;
AutorefreshSessionHelper.IsRequestForAutoRefresh(request);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This snippet enables writing to Form collection and then disables it again.  Tested on ASP.NET 3.5.

```
var request = new HttpRequest("", url, "");
var formType = request.Form.GetType();
formType.GetMethod("MakeReadWrite", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(request.Form, null);

request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] = eventTarget;

formType.GetMethod("MakeReadOnly", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(request.Form, null);
```

Comment: I was searching this answer for like 3 days.Thank you for taking your precious time to do the good to world.I really appreciate your work @Gedas Kutka

Answer (score 0):

I'm always of the mind that for unit tests it is ok to bypass some of the protections imposed by object visibility.

So with that in mind, HttpRequest's "Form" property is of type NameValueCollection, which has a protected IsReadOnly property. Reflection will help you out here:

```
var pi = typeof(NameObjectCollectionBase).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
pi.SetValue(request.Form, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a good unit test, because you are basically trying to test ASP.net. And ASP.net doesn't have much classes you can mock since there are no interfaces.

I guess there is a method beneath this that you want to test, which accepts the contents of the form. I suggest you try to test that.

Comment: It's not a unit test - it's just part of setting up data for a UT.  You can tell by the fact that I'm not verifying anything in that snippet.